# NullPointerException not being thrown on Lollipop

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-5.0-lollipop

This code (jar file) was written by somebody else, It is not very clean but it works fine on other (older) versions of Android but on Lollipop there is a problem, NullPointerException is thrown only in debug mode, otherwise the test application simply hangs. This behaviour is seen only on Lollipop.

I can reproduce the issue using String.

```
public class MyPlugin implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
    init();
    // Initialize done.
    }

    // Internally triggered when plug-in has to be stopped.

    private void stopPlugin(String message){
    try
    {
        Log.w("MyPlugin", "Lets make exception happen");
        String test=null;
        int value = test.length();
        Log.w("MyPlugin", "String Length " + value);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.w("MyPlugin", "The exception was handled");
    }
  }
}
```

In older versions of android when "test.length();" is called, NullPointerException is thrown but on Lollipop it does not trigger an exception. But if I get into debug mode exception is thrown.

Any idea why that is the reason?

Comment: This behavior is (IMO) downright implausible.  But if it really is happening it is a serious platform bug.

Comment: @Vishvesh: as in posted code length method is called when test is null. Where test is initialised??

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i was trying to reproduce the issue. The test is not initialized.

Comment: @StephenC Is it possible that I have done something silly in my code which is responsible for the issue? When I try the same thing in my app, the exception is thrown. Problem is with the jar file.

Comment: It is possible that you haven't recompiled ... or that you are running an old JAR.  It is also possible that `stopPlugin` isn't being called at all.  But if you are really executing `stopPlugin` code that corresponds exactly to that source code, the platform is broken.  That code should always throw an NPE, and the `catch` should always catch it.

Comment: I have logs before the calls and they all show up and nothing after that. The "stopPlugin" is called on a worker thread when the plug-in is going down. I will investigate the issue further. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Sounds like it's waiting for a debugger for some reason... Maybe there is a new build seeing for that?

Comment: There is a known issue with exception handling under the debugger in 5.02. https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/123720/ fixes the issue.

Comment: @IanNi-Lewis Can you please post this as answer? I tested the jar on 5.02, the issue is not reproducible now.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a result of Java optimization. Since the length is not assigned to a variable, statement test.length() is removed by optimizer as redundant.

Instead just do

```
Log.w("MyPlugin", "Lets make exception happen");
throw new NullPointerException();
```

This will surely work.

Comment: Yes, throwing NPE from there seems to work. I will make some changes to confirm the optimization.

Comment: Updated the code, still seeing the same problem. I am using size returned by length() method. I still don't understand why it just hangs.

Comment: Depending on how you updated the code. I would put something like  Log.d("Test", "The length is " + test.length()) which should crash.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with exception handling under the debugger in 5.02. android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/123720 fixes the issue.